# While loop does not terminate despite condition not fulfilled with scanf

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I have a very simple 9 line program:

```
# include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    char input[20];
    scanf("%s20", input);

    while (input != "stop") {
      printf("%s\n", input);
      scanf("%s20", input);
    }
}
```

I am first reading a string from the user and then echoing it back. This works fine. However when the program receives the string "stop" i would expect the while-loop to terminate. It does not and I have to stop the loop with Ctr+C. Why is that?

Comment: `while (input != "stop")` ==> `while (strcmp(input, "stop"))`

Comment: `scanf("%s20", input);` ==> `scanf("%19s", input);` ==> `if (scanf("%19s", input) != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: `void main()` ==> `int main()` ==> `int main(void)`